# How can I check for GCP projects not in a VPC Service Control Perimeter using bash?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am looking for a way to use a bash script with gcloud to:

- Generate a list of all current projects in the org
- Check each project to see if it is in a VPC Service control perimeter and list which perimeter name.
- Identify projects that are not in a VPC Service control perimeter.

I've had no luck finding a way to script this. I'd like to be able to easily generate this list and identify projects that are not in a vpcsc. Thanks!

Comment: `I've had no luck finding a way to script this.` but what have you tried? Otherwise it can be understood like your looking for someone to do this for you

Comment: I've had luck generating a list of all of the projects in the organization and then running commands against that list, but I'm having zero luck finding any way to get details about any of the vpcsc perimeters using gcloud.  Really I'm at the end of my rope just looking to see if there is a gcloud command I should be looking at for this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/manage-service-perimeters#gcloud I think this can help

Answer (score 0):

I don't use service perimeters and so it's challenging to write|test a solution but here are some pointers.

###### 1. Projects

[`ServicePerimeterConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.servicePerimeters#serviceperimeterconfig) [`resources`](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.servicePerimeters#ServicePerimeterConfig.FIELDS.resources) are of the form `project/{project_number}`.

So, when you enumerate the projects, you'll want to use the `projectNumber`:

```bash
gcloud projects list \
--format="value(projectId,projectNumber)"
```

Consider putting these into an associative array keyed on `projectNumber` so that you can return the more useful `projectId`.

###### 2. Service Perimeters

```bash
gcloud access-context-manager perimeters list \
--format=...
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/manage-service-perimeters#formatted-list) is unclear. [`--format`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--format) is a global `gcloud` flag and should support `value`, `json` and `yaml`.

[`servicePerimeters`](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/reference/rest/v1/accessPolicies.servicePerimeters) is a little gnarly (deep) but you probably want a second associative array keyed on `projectNumber` (again) with the `name` or `title` as the value.

You should be able to use [`scope`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#scope)`("project")` in the format string to extract the project number.

It's possible that you can map the `servicePerimeters` using gcloud `--format` (and transforms) only but it may be easier to pipe `--format=json` into something like `jq` and munge there.

> 1. Can one Project be in multiple Perimeters?
> 2. Can a Perimeter include a no-longer-exists Project?
> 3. `servicePerimeter` includes `status` and `spec` lists of projects

###### 3. In|Not-In

Array #1 contains all the projects. Those in Array #2 (which may be a duplicative test but) gives you projects in a service perimeter.

So, you could iterate over #1 and if it's in Array #2 put it in the "in" list otherwise put it in the "out" list.